# Table row colors change

Tags: jquery

Hello friends i want to change background color of every `<tr>` i am trying to do the same not getting the result i know there is some problem in my code. Please help me out

Following is my code check online **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QnVdE/)**

**SCRIPT**

```
var b = new Array('col_one','col_two','col_three');

$('#tbl tr').each(function(){

var a = 0;

$('#tbl tr').addClass(b[a])

a++;


})
```

**CSS**

```
.col_one
{
    background:#000099;
}
.col_two
{
    background:#009966;
}
.col_three
{
    background:#663333;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now.

http://jsfiddle.net/QnVdE/3/

Comment: hi @MajoB thanks for help . i m trying to paste your cpde on my web page but its not giving the same result plz check my code and tell me what is the problem in my code here online demo link http://jsfiddle.net/QnVdE/7/ ..... sorry for asking more

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are declaring `a` to be `0` at each iteration, you can pass a variable to the anon function of `each` to get the index of the elements being iterated:

```
$('#tbl tr').each(function(idx){

   // $(this) refers to the jQuery object of each tr
   $(this).addClass(b[idx%3]); // re-use colors when idx > 3
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QnVdE/2/

Comment: thanks for help but i want to apply css on `<tr>` continually your code only applying on first 3 `<tr>`

Comment: @Kamal I did an edit, did you see that? the part with `idx%3`

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = new Array('col_one','col_two','col_three');
var a = 0;
$('#tbl tr').each(function(){
if(a > 2){a=0;}
$(this).addClass(b[a]);

a++;


})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = ['col_one','col_two','col_three'];
var a = 0;
$('#tbl tr').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass(b[a % b.length]);
    a++;
});
```